# jassor Increase the width and height of the nested slider

Tags: jquery-ui, jssor

I have downloaded the jassor. The nested slider is the perfect solution for our requirement. But the problem is client need full size images in the slider (90 % height, 100% width of the window). How the size can be changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the size of 'outer container' and 'slides' container.
Btw, jssor slider will always keep aspect ratio while scale.

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/tip-arrange-layout-adjust-size.html

Comment: Thanks. I can see following containers. "sliderh1_container", "sliderh2_container", "sliderh3_container", slider1_container. But not able to find 'outer container' and 'slides' container

Comment: The main container is 'slider1_container'. Also, please adjust size for 'slides' container (<div u="slides" ...)